# How should I show that this integral is 0?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration

They want me to show this, but I already know that since it is a closed curve, the integral is $0$.

> Show that $\int_Cf=0$ where $C:|z|=\sqrt2$ and $f(z)=\frac{(z^2+2)}{z^2+3}$.

Do I just do this stuff?
\begin{align*}
C&=\sqrt2e^t, t\in(-\pi, \pi)\\
\int_Cf &= \int^\pi_{-\pi} f(C(t))C'(t)dt&u=C(t)\\
&=\int^{-\sqrt2}_{-\sqrt2} f(u)du\\
&=0
\end{align*}

Comment: $C$ being a closed curve is not enough.

Comment: What else should I say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, show that the residues of the poles that $C$ encloses sum to zero. In this case, show that $C$ encloses no poles of $f(z)$.

Comment: Thanks, That nudged me into the right direction to research.